# Sorting records by calculated field computed in the model

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-admin

So I need to ve able to sort the records by a calculated field which is calculated in the model side .

So my model is something like:

```py
    class User(models.Model):
        data = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False,)
        average = None

        def get_deviation(self):
            return abs(self.average- self.data)

        get_deviation.short_description = 'deviation'
        get_deviation.allow_tags = True
```

And in my admin Model:

```py
    class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('data')

        def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
            avg_val = User.objects.aggregate(Avg('data'))['data__avg']
            User.average = avg_val 
            list_display = ('data','get_deviation')
            return super(UserAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

So I need to be able to sort by the new field in the record list . 
any advice?

Comment: You need to be clearer about where `average` is coming from and how it is set.

Comment: I don't think it actually makes any difference but I added it